# How do I create a shared tmux session at startup?

Tags: linux, tmux, gnu-screen

Using a raspberry pi attached to an lcd. I'd like the pi to create a shared session 'foobar' when it boots. I added a command to .bashrc, but it instantiates in an infinite loop.

The goal is to be able to ssh into the pi and see the remote terminal mirrored on the pi's lcd.

Comment: While an interesting Q, it is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck. -- (That said, the screen utility might work for your needs, but I don't have any experience with it on the rpi.)

Comment: I'd assume the solution lies in a bash script of some kind. Is the issue with how I phrased the question? I.e 'Using bash, how would I...'

Screen has the same issue as tmux, when each session loads, it runs .bashrc which results in an infinite loop (or until the max number of embedded sessions is reached)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, Readers need a way to reproduce your situation. I guess including a minimal .bashrc that causes the problem would a good place to start. (Someone would have answered by now if they knew the answer to gain the rep points ;-) ... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.bashrc` you need to check if you are already in tmux session and if no then start or attach to tmux session. Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306165.